# Apache Airflow: Pass variable in jinja include

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jinja2, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am currently using following statement in Apache airflow

```
s10_test_load = bigquery.BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="10_test_load",
    configuration={
            "query": {
                        "query": "{% include './scripts/10_test_load.sql' %}",                           
                        "useLegacySql": False,
            },                  
    },
)
```

This statement is working fine and is executing sql from the script file.

I would like dynamically use the file name from a variable like following

```
file_name='./scripts/10_test_load.sql'

s10_test_load = bigquery.BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="10_test_load",
    configuration={
            "query": {
                        "query": "{% include file_name %}",                          
                        "useLegacySql": False,
            },                  
    },
)
```

How I can pass a python variable inside jinja include?

Answer (score 2):

You could use f-string formating and add an extra pair of curly braces like this:

```
file_name='bq/queries/10_test_load.sql'

t2 = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
   task_id="10_test_load",
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": f"{{% include '{file_name}' %}}",                          
            "useLegacySql": False,
        },                  
    },             
)
```

This gets rendered the desired way:
[image]

Comment: @alex-lipkin Please accept the answer if you found it helpful. Check "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)"

Comment: When I used it, it didn't work
\n
 f"{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='{t1_task_id}')['metadata']['name'] }}",

('{ '
 "task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='sales-forecast-train')['metadata']['name'] "
 '}')

Comment: @Hao Please file another question explaining your issue.