# How pass airflow jinja vairable value to function inside bigquery operator

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, jinja2

I wrote some code that generates from_date and to_date based on the current run date in airflow. So I utilised the jinja variables 'ds_nodash' and did some calculations on top of it.
My code is throwing an error. While executing, it does not pass any value to the function, only the string '{{ no_dash }}' and not the value.

```
def gen_pg_count_update_query(ts_nodash_val):
ts_format_string = "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"
current_datetime = datetime.strptime(ts_nodash_val, ts_format_string)
datetime_to = current_datetime - timedelta(minutes=max_pipeline_delay)
datetime_from = datetime_to - timedelta(hours=frequency_hour)
unix_from = time.mktime(datetime_from.timetuple()) * 1000
unix_to = time.mktime(datetime_to.timetuple()) * 1000

dynamic_query = f" insert into table1 (col1, col2 ) select (select count (*) from tablex where updateat  between '{datetime_from}' and '{datetime_to}' ), (select count (*) from tabley where updateat_unix  between '{unix_from}' and '{unix_from}' )"
return dynamic_query

update_pg_count = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
            task_id=f"pg_count_insert_job",
            configuration={
                "query": {
                    "query": gen_pg_count_update_query('{{ ds_nodash }}'),
                    "useLegacySql": False,
                }
            },
            location=bq_region,
            dag=dag
        )
```

Comment: Replace `"query": gen_pg_count_update_query('{{ ds_nodash }}')` with  `"query": "{{ gen_pg_count_update_query(ds_nodash) }}"`

Comment: Hi @jisto, Are you using  Google Cloud Compose?If yes then can you provide the composer and airflow version?

Comment: @kiranmathew Yes we are using GCP composer. Composer v2.2.1, Airflow v2.4.3

Comment: Can you share the error message you are facing?

Comment: @kiranmathew There's is no code error, '{{ no_dash }}' is not getting replaced by value while executing so my function is getting the same string as input

Comment: Hi @jisto,could you take a look at these [link1](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/templating) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324891/).Can you try this `gen_pg_count_update_query(f “{ ds_nodash }”)` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can [use functions in jinja template](https://saidvandeklundert.net/2020-12-24-python-functions-in-jinja/).

Replace `"query": gen_pg_count_update_query('{{ ds_nodash }}')` with `"query": "{{ gen_pg_count_update_query(ds_nodash) }}"`

Comment: Not solved above method, operator pass text '{{gen_pg_count_update_query(ds_nodash) }}' to BigQueryInsertJobOperator,
error as follows 

ERROR - Exception rendering Jinja template for task 'bq_meta_insert_xxx', field 'configuration'. Template: {'query': {'query': '{{ gen_pg_count_update_query(ds_nodash) }}', 'useLegacySql': False}}